# running a geb test from a java class

Tags: java, groovy, geb

I've recently stumbled across [geb](http://www.gebish.org/) and it looks like a good way to perform integration tests on our web applications. Our platforms are all java based and from reading that

> "Geb provides first class support for functional web testing via
>   integration with popular testing frameworks such as ...JUnit,
>   TestNG..."

i assumed it would be easy to execute a test from a java class (testng test?).

I'm new to groovy and geb.

So far I have included geb-testng and groovy in my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.geb</groupId>
    <artifactId>geb-testng</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

... However i can't find any examples of creating a test and running it from a java class.

help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geb is designed for, and can only be used from, Groovy code. This is mainly due to the dynamic nature of its APIs. What you *can* choose is which test framework to use (JUnit, TestNG, Spock, etc.). As Geb itself is just a library, it can also be used without a test framework, for example to automate an interaction with a website.

If you need to stick to Java, you'll have to use something like Selenium2, which is what Geb uses under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

I stumpled upon this question while searching a Geb-TestNG example. Here is what is working for me:

```
import geb.testng.GebTest
import org.testng.annotations.Test


class GroovyYourTestClass extends GebTest {

    @Test
    void "should test something"() {
        to YourPageObject
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best alternative to Geb if you're using Java is IMHO Selenide (http://selenide.org)

example from Quick Start Guide:

```
@Test
public void userCanLoginByUsername() {
  open("/login");
  $(By.name("user.name")).setValue("johny");
  $("#submit").click();
  $(".loading_progress").should(disappear); // Waits until element disappears
  $("#username").shouldHave(text("Hello, Johny!")); // Waits until element gets text
}
```

It's independent from your testing framework and therefore can be used with e.g. JUnit, TestNG, Cucumber, ScalaTest, JBehave